# How would I go about while looping this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm creating a part of my program that raises a error when the user doesn't input a integer. Below is my code...

```
try:
    pw_length_ask = int(raw_input("How long would you like your password to be? "))
    final_pw_length = pw_length + int(pw_length_ask.strip())
    print("Pass length set to " + str(final_pw_length))
except ValueError:
    print("You must enter a number.")
    int(raw_input("How long would you like your password to be? "))
```

It works great until the user is asked to enter a number again...

[ValueError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyNWE.png)

It just throws a ValueError then crashes. So how do I make it so that instead of giving the Value Error it repeats the question until the user gives correct input?

Comment: Please post error traceback here instead of linking to a screenshot

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122 re: why we don't welcome images of code (or errors). They're not searchable, they're unfriendly to assistive technologies like screen readers, they make the question less useful to others if/when the links eventually rot, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put it in a while loop, like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        pw_length_ask = int(raw_input("How long would you like your password to be? "))
        final_pw_length = pw_length + int(pw_length_ask)
        print("Pass length set to " + str(final_pw_length))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter a number.")
```

The error likely came from the `input` you placed in the `except` block.

Comment: `while`, not `While`

Comment: This also uses a `strip()` on an integer `pw_length_ask` so will likely trigger an error. The strip should after the `raw_input`.